# Java SE - custom button (Jcomponent) and ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcomponent

I implemented class MyButton, which extends class Jcomponent. And the problem is, that i have some MyButton objects in main class (implements ActionListener), and I would like to add action listener to them.

How to handle it? So i can use addActionListener?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need the functionality of the `JButton` but at the same time, wanted to add something to it's feature, than extend `JButton` itself, why to extend `JCompoent` which is way up in the hierarchy. Extend the class that comes closer to whose functionality you need and add few more of yours. The name suggested by you `MyButton` for the class which extends `JComponent` is not giving good vibes, related to what you been coding. Extend `JButton`, if this is what you want, with extended features of your choice. Else you might soon find yourself reinventing the wheel for the `JButton`,yourself

Answer (score 3):

- use [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) / [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) in the case `MyButton objects` doesn't implements / inherits `JButton` or `AbstractButton` methods
- if implements `JButton` or `AbstractButton` then you can use

  a) `ButtonModel`

  b) `Swing Action`

  c) `ActionListener`
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)